How to resolve Build error:Unable to build
This is my first time on Solana Playground and I am unable to build. Where did I go wrong?

At first, check your wallet connection for play ground in the bottom of site.
Second, check your wallet balance.
At the end, check your code base.
You can check doc for solana playground below link.
https://solana.com/docs/intro/quick-start

